# Практическое использование исключений с#

Tags: c#, исключения, xnet

Вот у меня есть этот код, я не совсем понял как в этом случае использовать исключение:

```
public static string PostRequest(string Url, string PostData = "", string UserAgent = "", string Referer = "", CookieDictionary Cookies = null, ProxyType ProxyProto = ProxyType.None, string ProxyString = "")
{
    request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(ProxyString);
    ...
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = request.Post(Url, PostData, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Cookies = response.Cookies;
        response_html = response.ToString();
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Как мне узнать, какое именно исключение вызвалось, то есть узнать в чем проблема - либо удаленный хост недоступен, либо сокс север не отвечает? Во всех примерах что я видел во время исключения вызывалось какое-нибудь логирование и функция завершалась. Но мне нужно сделать немного по-другому, если сокс не отвечает: попыпаться отправить запрос через некоторое время. Обычно бы я сделал просто так:

```
while(i<3)
{
    data = PostRequest();
    if(data != null)
        break;
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
}
```

Но как мне выкинуть исключение, допустим, с кодом ответа, что мол сокс-сервер не отвечает, и пока не придет ответ, либо пока все три итерации не пройдут, пытаться отправить запрос? Заранее спасибо!

UPD: Немного посмотрел на исключения в библиотеке xNet и они как-то странно работают. Там есть три типа исключений xNet.NetException, xNet.ProxyException и еще один тип. Но почему-то всегда выбрасывается дефолтное (остальные не ловятся). Я хотел узнать, можно ли использовать такой подход при определении типа исключений:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    //MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());

    if(ex.InnerException.ToString().IndexOf("xNet.ProxyException:") > 0 && ex.InnerException.ToString().IndexOf("Socket") > 0)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("F");
        throw new xNet.ProxyException();  

    }

    throw new xNet.NetException();  


}
```

То есть определить тип исключения по тексту в нем и потом уже выбросить нужное? Кажется что так неправильно делать, но по-другому я не нашел как их различать, потому что всегда Exception выбрасывается.

Comment: `(ex.InnerException is xNet.ProxyException)` обычно вполне достаточно

Comment: Да, действительно. Еще раз выручили, спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Исходя из того, что библиотека xNet (стоило кстати упомянуть это название) использует собственные исключения, можно сделать так:

```
public static string PostRequest(string Url, string PostData = "", string UserAgent = "", string Referer = "", CookieDictionary Cookies = null, ProxyType ProxyProto = ProxyType.None, string ProxyString = "")
{
    request.Proxy = Socks5ProxyClient.Parse(ProxyString);
    ...
    try
    {
        HttpResponse response = request.Post(Url, PostData, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        Cookies = response.Cookies;
        response_html = response.ToString();
    }
    catch (xNet.Net.HttpException ex)
    {
        // ошибка случилась внутри библиотеки
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // все остальные ошибки
    }
}
```

Comment: В том коде только xNetовские исключения вроде как могут появится, нет? Еще там как-то странно сделано, когда прокси не отвечает, выбрасывается исключение что не может подключиться к такому-то хосту, а не то что прокси-сервер недоступен.

Comment: Как минимум, внутри первого обработчика можно проверить `ex.Status`, там должно быть достаточное пояснение.

Comment: Papin, окей, погляжу - спасибо за коммент!

Answer (score 4):

Поставьте брейкпоинт на строчку `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);` и попытайтесь найти в отладчике отличия в пойманном исключении. Если библиотека `Socks5ProxyClient` написано пряморукими программистами - то отличие будет в типе исключения. Иначе придется догадываться по косвенным признакам.

Comment: А если мне самому нужно будет выбросить исключение с каким-нибудь параметром и отталкиваясь от значения этого параметра как-нибудь организовать цикл как в примере, то как это организовать в коде? И можно ли вообще, потому что я не совсем представляю как это будет выглядеть.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, можете конечно и свое исключение бросить, но перед этим не кисло было бы его как-то обозначить, например так: `public class MyCustomException : Exception {...}` , бросив потом своё исключение вы смело можете его перехватывать

Comment: @Dmitry, допустим, я объявлю свое исключение и брошу его. Но как мне туда, например код ошибки передать чтобы потом его извлечь, и как мне это все дело устроить в цикле? То есть пока бросается мое исключение с таким-то кодом, выполнять то-то? Не подскажете?

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, отчего же, подскажу: `if(a>b){ throw new MyCustomException("a>b");}`

Comment: @Dmitry ну это понятно да, но я имел в виду что-то вроде:MyException ex;
ex.code = 0;
//code это свойство, заданное мной, например
while(ex.code != 200 && i<3)
{
 try
 {
  response = PostRequest()

 } catch (ex) {

  
  
 }
}

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, не проблема, расширте своё исключение нужными свойствами

Comment: @АлександрПушкин, так как  `MyCustomException`  это ваш класс вы можете добавлять туда любые поля. но в данному случае проще сделать исключение нужного типа еще одно и все while положить в try...catch

Comment: @Grundy, понятно, что-то подобное наверное и сделаю, всем спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

1. Надо использовать `ex.ToString()`, а не `ex.Message`.
2. Надо обрабатывать только те исключения, которые являются ожидаемыми.

Comment: А какая разница что использовать? И можно ли в пользовательском исключении свои свойства использовать?

Comment: 1. Ну выведи и посмотри - там будет ещё стектрейс. 2. Да.

Comment: ToString() - это хорошо... но не в мессейдж-боксе же?! Ну нельзя же пользователя пугать стектрейсами.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, в коде из вопроса есть только MsgBox